# What happens when a subclass object is assigned as a superclass object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

So I have a question about a superclass A and subclass B, where A has 2 public variables and B has 1 more.

I saw this snippet of code:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a = b;
```

What does that last line do? I don't really understand what actually happens when you use "=" between 2 classes in an inheritance relationship.

Comment: What would it do if instead you had `int x = 0; int y = 1; x = y;`?

Comment: Objects are not assigned. References are assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple assignment. `=` is an assignment operator.

Lets be clear of below points.

1. In Java when an Object is created and it is accessible via. reference. A reference refer to an Object.
2. At a time one reference can refer to only one object
3. A reference of type X can refer to an object of type X or any sub types (extending in case X is a class or implementing if X is an interface).

Now Suppose there are two classes `Super` and `Sub` such that `Sub extends Super`.

```
 SuperClass reference = new SubClass();
```

This is allowed as SubClass inherits from SuperClass. 
Above we have an object of type SubClass created in the heap and it is accessible via. reference named `reference`

Note that a reference of type `SubClass` can not refer to object of `SuperClass`. Lets see in brief why so ?. If the reference of type `SubClass` was allowed to refer an Object of type `SuperClass` then it would have been allowed to invoke additional methods (functions) defined by `SubClass` (`SubClass` would have inherited all methods of `SuperClass` and would also have defined few additional methods). Now this would have made the application to crash as the Object of `SuperClass` only has methods defined in `SuperClass` but does not have any additional methods defined by `SubClass`. Hence compiler prevents it during compile time. Its a compile time error to have a reference of type `SubClass` referring to an object of type `SuperClass`

Now lets look at the code as mentioned in the question

```
 SuperClass a = new SuperClass();
 SubClass b = new SubClass();
 a = b;
```

Line 1 : We have an object of SuperClass being referred by a variable of type SuperClass named `a`

Line 2 : We have an object of SubClass being referred by a variable of type SubClass named `b`

Line 3 : We have an assignment where `a` is assigned to refer the same object as referred by `b`. So now we have both references referring to the object of type `SubClass` created at line 2. Object of typer `SuperClass` created at line 1 (with the current available code mentioned in the question) is not having any references so it is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thank you so much! it's much clearer now. So if we had "b = a" instead (at line 3) that would result in a runtime/compilation error? since a variable of type SubClass cannot refer to an object of SuperClass?

Comment: @din abarbanel yes that is right, I have edited my answer to include the explanation for this too. Hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Nothing 'happens'. The object referred to by variable 'b' is a single object. It is at the same time an instance of a B and an instance of an A.

When you execute the assignment `a = b`, the object previously referred to by variable 'a' becomes inaccessible.  Considerations of that old object do not enter into this discussion.

After the assignment, 'a' and 'b' refe to the same object. The object is unchanged. It is still an instance of a B and an instance of an A.

Perhaps the block in your understanding is the distinction between objects and the variables that refer to those objects?

Answer (score 0):

Lets play with inheritance, we have a class A and a class B.

```
class A{
    private int a;
    A(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public int valA(){
        return this.a;
    }
}

class B extends A{
    B(int b) {
        super(b);
    }
    public void printA(){
        System.out.println("The Val of A: "+valA());
    }
    public int valA(){return super.valA()*5;}
}
```

What's special here that we have a method in B that is not defined in class A. Nevertheless, when we create an object of class B and assign it to A, we don't get any error.

Now we create two objects, of A and B respectively and then assign the object of B to that of A.

```
    A a = new A(5);
    B b = new B(4);
    a=b;
    System.out.println(a.valA());
```

When we execute, we get the value as 20. The answer you know is because of Runtime polymorphism that we have overrides valA(). But when we want to execute printA() from a

```
    a.printA();
```

The error is a compile time. The reason is simple, the compiler cannot find printA(). And the reason is it was never declared here. But you may ask we defined in B and assigned to A.

The simple answer is compiler ignores it and overrides only the methods and parameters that are declared in B and A.

> **Can we do the opposite?**

Lets try it.

```
b = a;
```

And simply we get the compile time error.

```
java: incompatible types: oops.inheritance.A cannot be converted to oops.inheritance.B
```

And yes the answer is very intuitive because the methods in B have not been A and the compiler knows that this may be a possible case and straight away throws an error that you are doing wrong.

### Now the answer you want.

It is possible to assign an object of subclass to reference of superclass but don't expect the properties and functions declared in B to be transferred because they are simply dumped.