# How to use returned value which isn't a variable

Tags: java, methods

I have two Java classes. I want the second class to return a `String` *"eee"* when it is called by the `main()` method of the first class, then I want that `main()` method to capture that `String` and use it in an `if` statement.

My question boils down to how may I work with a value returned by a method in another class which is not an already declared variable?

I can return *"eee"* and Eclipse will compile and run the code, but that's as far as I've got.  I can't figure out how to pick it up in the `main()` method.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Customer.findCustomer(customers,input,true);
}

public class Customer {
    public static String findCustomer(Customer[] customers, String search, boolean byName) {        
        ...
    if (foundCustomer.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        System.out.println("Customer cannot be found in the system.");
        return "eee";
    }
```

In the `main()` method I want to be able to use an if statement thus:

```
If(value returned !="eee"){
     do something
}
```

Comment: Use java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase()  to compare the string , the string equality shouldn't be done with == .

Comment: java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase() use this for checking equality in String.

Comment: Create a variable and use `=` to assign the returned result

Comment: The return value is always a value, not a variable.  If for examole you wrote ```String foo = "eee";  return foo;``` then what is returned is the value of variable ```foo```, not the variable ```foo```, which in any case ceases to exist.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that @another-dave ... I'm only a college student learning the basics.

Comment: No problem. The concept of "variable" can be trickier than it appears on the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     if (!Customer.findCustomer(customers, input, true).equalsIgnoreCase("eee")) {
      do something
     }
    }
```

Comment: This answer exactly met my needs, whereby I couldn't create a new variable in the main method (it's for an assignment at school). Thanks a lot @Dinesh!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the result to a variable like so

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    value = Customer.findCustomer(customers,input,true);
    if(value returned !="eee"){ /*do something*/ }
```

Except you need to set customers, and input equal to something first.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    input = 'test';
    customers = new Customer[];
    value = Customer.findCustomer(customers,input,true);
    if(value returned !="eee"){ /*do something*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable (reference of type String so that it can refer to String object) and use `=` to assign the returned string object. Now perform the check (if else etc) operation by using `.` operator i.e.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
   String retValue =   Customer.findCustomer(customers,input,true); 
   if(retValue.equals("eee"){
          //do processing
   }
}
```

For reference you can see the answer 
[reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437269/504133) for references and objects and `=` operator